# How do you compile ES6 modules for Wordpress child themes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ecmascript-6

**In this brave new world of @import whats the workflow to write a ES6 module have it compile into a dependency script and your main script for inclusion using 'script_loader_tag' into your theme**

I stopped being a front-end Dev a couple years ago hence the odd mix of capabilities.
I am attempting to create a threejs scene that targets a div on an existing child theme (divi). I'm getting frustrated using three /js instead of /jsm . As all tutorials are obviously in ES6.

This is a simple feature and all my google searches have return how to do a complete theme in webpack / react etc.. I'm hoping someone here would be able to point me in the right direction